# Viewpager and navigation bar on top of it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-navigation-bar

It seems that this question was asked many times before.
At least i found a lot on the internet and SO in particular.
But none of the answers helped, don't know why.

I've created a simple blank tabbed activity project in Android Studio 2.2.2
Haven't touched anything in it except one addition - adding an imageview.
Here is an activity layout, which was generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.company.me.navbartest.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Didn't change anything here.
And here is a fragment's layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.company.me.navbartest.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The only addition here is an ImageView at the bottom of the fragment.
Didn't touch the code at all. Don't know if it's needed, but just in case it's here: http://pastebin.com/FuUiGpyH

Here is the result:
[image: Navbar troubles]

This was taken on KitKat but it's same on Marshmallow.
See the small green ears? That's from the ImageView i've added. It's an icon of an android logo.

I've tried different combinations of "fitsSystemWindows" flag. No success. I guess i just don't quite understand how it works and should be used.

Also tried changing the root object of the fragment - same results.

So the main question is - how to fix this? How to make sure this ImageView is shown where it was supposed to?

The gradle specs are:

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 25
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

Comment: try using `adjustViewBounds="true"` and `scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: You can add bottom margin to your imageview

Comment: This won't fix the real issue. I mean ImageView is just an example of how any control looks like in this case. Imaging that there is an EditText instead of it. Or another view group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like i found a solution.

The "problem" was in toolbar's scroll flags. I guess the template was supposed to be used with a list and specific scrolling (the one where a toolbar is collapsed), and so the flags were

```
scroll | enterAlways
```

But my pager didn't have any lists and wasn't supposed to be scrollable so i just removed them and everything is normal now!

Another "workaround" is to surround AppBarLayout in a LinearLayout. Also helps, but don't know about the sideeffects. Haven't tested it much.